# How to properly set up the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

(**tl;dr** at the bottom)

Currently I'm setting up the properties by:

```
let mpic = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()
func setInfoCenterCredentials(_ postion: NSNumber, _ duration: NSNumber, _ playbackState: Int) {

    let mySize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
    let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize:mySize) { sz in
        return getCoverImage()
    }
    mpic.nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: globalTrackName,
                           MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: globalArtistName,
                           MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt,
                           MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: postion,
                           MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: duration,
                           MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: playbackState]
}
```

Used with the Spotify iOS SDK:

```
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController, didChangePosition position: TimeInterval) {
    if self.isChangingProgress {
        return
    }
    let position = Float(positionDouble / durationDouble)
    let duration = Float((sptAudioStreamCtr?.metadata.currentTrack!.duration)!)    
    globalPositionNumber = NSNumber(value: position)
    globalDurationNumber = NSNumber(value: duration)

    setInfoCenterCredentials(globalPositionNumber, globalDurationNumber, 1)
}
```

This works pretty well so far.

**Problem #1**

When I'm hitting the pause button:

[image]

The music stops, but the time keeps counting down. I have printed out `globalPositionNumber` and `globalDurationNumber` on their `didSet` and they aren't getting changed. As expected.

Then I have implemented:

```
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController, didChangePlaybackStatus isPlaying: Bool) {

    if !isPlaying {
        setInfoCenterCredentials(globalPositionNumber, globalDurationNumber, 0)
    }
}
```

Problem now. Hitting pause, results in the timer being reset and starting from 0, once resumed.

**Problem #2**

[image] [image]

If I'm swiping up the control panel from within the App, the counters are synced. If I'm leaving the app with the home button and swipe up the control panel from the home screen, the counter starts counting from zero.

**Problem #3**

If I'm hittin the pause/forward/back buttons from the home screen, they are working well. If I'm swiping up the control panel with my app active and am hitting the buttons, nothing happens.

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated

**tl;dr**

**Problem 1**: Time couter of control panel resetted using `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` 1 or not stopping if not set.

**Problem 2**: Time counter starts on zero if left the App during the track.

**Problem 3**: Hitting the action buttons on the control panel with the app active has no effect.

Edit:

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder : Bool {
    return true
}

override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let ctr = SPTAudioHandler.shared.audioCtrl {
        let rc = event!.subtype
        switch rc {
        case .remoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            ctr.setIsPlaying(!ctr.playbackState.isPlaying, callback: nil)
        case .remoteControlPlay:
            ctr.setIsPlaying(!ctr.playbackState.isPlaying, callback: nil)
        case .remoteControlPause:
            ctr.setIsPlaying(!ctr.playbackState.isPlaying, callback: nil)
        case .remoteControlNextTrack:
            globalBackForthInt = 1
            getNextSpotifyTrack(SPTAudioHandler.shared.spotifyTracks, SPTAudioHandler.shared.playerView)
            globalTrackIndexPath = globalTrackIndexPath + 1
        case .remoteControlPreviousTrack:
            getNextSpotifyTrack(SPTAudioHandler.shared.spotifyTracks, SPTAudioHandler.shared.playerView)
            globalBackForthInt = -1
            getNextSpotifyTrack(SPTAudioHandler.shared.spotifyTracks, SPTAudioHandler.shared.playerView)
            globalTrackIndexPath = globalTrackIndexPath - 1
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Everything else is set in `setInfoCenterCredentials`

Comment: shouldnt be. the framework works pretty well

Comment: Where are you defining the time counter?

Comment: like posted in the question, at `func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController, didChangePosition position: TimeInterval) {`

Comment: How is isChangingProgress managed? This seems to be the variable controlling the time counter.

Comment: when a new track is loaded, this var will be changed to true, once it plays it will be changed to false. also it's a global variable.

Comment: but that is not the problem (i guess). because the track count is working in the whole app, just once the app is turned into the background, it's restarted

Comment: like i have listed in the question: the issue is, that when the app is in the background, the counter starts from zero. when inforcenter swiped up, the counter is async and the buttons aren't working IF app is in foreground.

Comment: since the framework is used by thousands and there is no report like this at the github, I dont think so.

Comment: no. not at all. everything is working well but the mentioned issues.

Comment: provided everything now, that has anything to do with the control center

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129739/discussion-between-gjz-and-david-seek).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was even more simple...

It was a matter of the **simulator**... All the bugs appeared on a simulator only. **Everything** works fine on an actual device.

Answer (score 3):

> I would suggest re-importing the framework to ensure there are no issues with integration.

As there are no negative reports on GitHub and the code seems fine, it may simply be an integration issue.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have awarded the bounty to you. Better than have it wasted. Thank you for your effort. But the answer is so freaking simple... Wish I would have tried before starting a bounty -.-