# Display iOS 11 Player Controller in Lock screen

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, ios11, control-center

I'm working on a music app which uses AVPlayer to stream audio online. But in iOS 11 the Player controller does not appear in lock screen although it appears for other apps (ex. Spotify).
Do I have to add something to info.plist? 
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly set up the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804655/how-to-properly-set-up-the-mpnowplayinginfocenter-in-swift-3)

Comment: Okay..I think I found what I need, I have to create MPNowplayinginfocenter object.